# preg_replace with exceptions doesn't work for me

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I got a "little" problem already...
I only want to replace some names with other names or something.
It works fine so far, but with some names I got a problem.

For example I want to replace `"Cho"` with `"Cho'Gath"`, 
but of course I don't want to replace `"Cho'Gath"` with `"Cho'Gath'Gath"`.

So therefore I created this regular expression, and replace all `"Cho"`'s except of `"Cho'Gath"`:

```
/\bCho(?!.+Gath)\b/i
```

This works and it doesn't replace `"Cho'Gath"`, but it also doesn't replace `"Cho Hello World Gath"` ... that is my first problem!

The second one is follwing: I also want to replace all `"Yi"`, but not `"Master Yi"`, so I tried the same with the following regular expression:

```
/\b(?!Master.+)Yi\b/i
```

This doesn't replace `"Master Yi"`, okay. But it also doesn't replace `"Yi"`, but it should do! (I also tried `/\b(?!Master(**\s**))Yi\b/i` but this also doesn't work)

So far I don't know what to do know... can anyone help me with that?

Comment: you know, what `.+` does, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is easily solved if you replace `.+` with the actual character that you want to match (or not to match): `'`, but let's have a look at the second one, this is quite interesting:

> I also want to replace all "Yi", but not "Master Yi", so I tried the
>   same with the following regular expression:
>
> ```
> /\b(?!Master.+)Yi\b/i
> ```

This is a negative lookahead on `\b`. The expression **does** match a single "Yi", but look what it does with "Master Yi":

```
Hello I am Master Yi
                 ^
                 \b
```

This boundary is not followed by "Master" but followed by "Yi". So your expression also matches the "Yi" in this string.

The negative lookahead is quite pointless because it checks if the boundary that is directly followed by "Yi" (remember that a lookahead assertion just "looks ahead" without moving the pointer forward) is not directly followed by "Master". This is always the case.

You could use a lookbehind assertion instead, but only without the (anyways unnecessary) `.+`, because lookbehind assertions must have fixed lengths:

```
/\b(?<!Master )Yi\b/i
```

matches every "Yi" that is not preceded by "Master ".

Comment: Hey man, Master Yi, works at all, but the expression with the `'` doesn't work for me!

Do you think the problem is, that I declare the expressions in an array, with `'` as the expression start and end, like this: `$search = array('/\bCho(?!\'Gath)\b/');`

(I have to escape the `'`, because otherwise it will throw errors)

Comment: Escaping is correct, the actual string then only contains the `'` char there. Are you sure that the string has this exact character (ASCII 39)? [See here](http://regex-test.com/share-url.php?url=validate/php/preg_replace&vp=%2F%5CbCho(%3F!'Gath)%5Cb%2F&vs=Cho'Gath%0ACho%0ACho%60Gath&vr=Foo&vc=Cho'Gath%0AFoo%0AFoo%60Gath) how it works.

Comment: Hm the strange thing is, when I want to replace with `/\bCho(?!.Gath)\b/` it also replaces `"Cho'Gath"` :/

Comment: then maybe `'` is actually a multibyte character. Did you check that?

Comment: I don't know how :(, but if so, what should I do then?

Comment: `var_dump` your string and check the length. To see what exact characters you have, you can also use something like `for($i=0,$c=strlen($string);$i<$c;++$i) printf("%s: %d \n", $string[$i], ord($string[$i]));` - then you *should* find `': 39` in the output.

Comment: Where I can find the output from printf? In the console?

Comment: same as echo. if you run the script via CLI: in the console. if you run it on the webserver: in your browser

Comment: For me the `'` are two chars... how is that possible? Maybe because of the charset? I chosed utf-8. So far `/\bCho(?!..Gath)\b/i` worked as u mentioned.

Comment: That's what I meant: utf-8 is a multibyte charset and your character is NOT `'` but a similar looking that is encoded as two bytes in utf-8. You should use the "u" flag for utf-8 support, this will work: `/\bCho(?!.Gath)\b/iu`. Another improvement would be to copy the exact character from your original string instead of the dot and save your php script as utf-8 too.

Answer (score 0):

For the first regex:

```
\bCho(?!.Gath)\b
```

For the second:

```
(?<!\bMaster )Yi\b
```

Your first regex had `.+` in it, that is one character, one or more times; and as quantifiers are greedy by default, this swallows the whole input before reluctantly giving back to match the next token (`G`).

Your second regex used a negative lookahead, what you wanted was a negative *lookbehind*. That is, a position where the text *before* that position does not match.

And note that regexes in lookbehinds must be of finite length.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the second expression, it works very well!!!

But the first one not :/
It still replaces `"Cho'Gath"` to `"Cho'Gath'Gath"`.

Do you think the problem is, that I declare the regular expressions in a array like this: `$search = array('/\bCho(?!.Gath)\b/i','HelloWorld', ...)`